# Xcode iCloud "Add the "iCloud containers" entitlement to your App ID"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, icloud, icloud-drive

1. For using iCloud Documents, is Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Apple ID's role admin?
2. I tested two accounts.

Result :

admin account - it has error that "**Your account already has a valid iOS Development certificate**".

[image]

member account - it has error that "**Communication with Apple failed**".

[image]

How to clear error that "Add the "iCloud containers" entitlement to your App ID"?

Comment: Maybe... press on the "Fix issue" button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use in both applications the same custom container ID. 
By default each project creates its own unique container id, but you need to use the same for different project.

So:

1) create custom id for the first application, similar to the suggested by XCode. Add it to custom container list.

2) Open CloudKit dashboard, to be sure that this container is created in your iTunesConnect account.

3) Open the second project/target and add there the same custom container.

Though I am not sure this is an effective way to synchronize databases or other big data. If you want to keep updated client' and admin' databases you can consider CloudKit based per-record synchronization.